# Recurrence relations of the form $T(n) = T(n-1) + (n-1)! n^k$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

In the context of recursive permutation-related algorithms, the following form of recurrence relations often comes up:
$$
T(n) = 1 \\
T(n) = T(n-1) + (n-1)! \cdot n^k
$$
where $k$ is usually 0, 1, or 2.

What can be said about the asymptotic behaviour of $T(n)$ (in terms of $\Theta$ or $O$ notation, and in general or for specific $k$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $a_n = T(n)$, $b_n = n^k (n-1)!$, $\Delta a_n = a_n - a_{n-1} = b_n$, $\Delta b_n = b_n - b_{n-1}$.

Hence
$$\Delta b_n = n^k (n-1)! - (n-1)^k (n-2)! = n^k (n-1)! \cdot ( 1 - \frac{(\frac{n-1}{n})^k}{n-1})$$
$$= n^k (n-1)! \cdot ( 1 - \frac{1+\text{o}(1)}{n-1}) = b_n (1+\text{o}(1)).$$
By Stolz–Cesàro theorem

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\Delta a_n}{\Delta b_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_n}{ b_n(1+\text{o}(1))}  = 1.$$
It follows that $T_n \sim n^k (n-1)! = n^{k-1} n!$ for $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align*}
T(n) & = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {(j - 1)!j^k }  = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {(n - j - 1)!(n - j)^k } 
\\
& = (n - 1)!n^k \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{(n - 1)}}\left( {1 - \frac{1}{n}} \right)^k  + \sum\limits_{j = 2}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{{(n - j) \cdots (n - 1)}}\left( {1 - \frac{j}{n}} \right)^k } } \right).
\end{align*}
From this it follows that
$$
T(n) = (n - 1)!n^k \left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right),
$$
as $n\to +\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$\sum_{p=2}^{n} (T(p)-T(p-1))=\sum_{p=2}^{n} (p-1)!.p^k$

By telescoping

$T(n)-T(1)=\sum_{p=2}^{n} (p-1)!.p^k$

As $T(1)=1$,

$T(n)=1+(n-1)!.n^k+(n-2)!.(n-1)^k+(n-3)!.(n-2)^k+ \sum_{p=2}^{n-3} (p-1)!.p^k$

Considering the last sum

$\sum_{p=2}^{n-3} (p-1)!.p^k=(n-3)!.(n-1)^k.\sum_{p=2}^{n-3} \frac{(p-1)!}{(n-3)!}.\frac{p^k}{(n-1)^k}$

$\leq(n-3)!.(n-1)^k.\sum_{p=2}^{n-3} \frac{(n-4)!}{(n-3)!}.\frac{(n-3)^k}{(n-1)^k}$

However $\frac{(n-4)!}{(n-3)!}.\frac{(n-3)^k}{(n-1)^k} \leq 1$ ($k\geq 1$)

So $\sum_{p=2}^{n-3} (p-1)!.p^k \leq (n-3)!(n-1)^k. (n-3-2+1)$

$\leq (n-2)!(n-1)^k$

We deduce that

$\sum_{p=2}^{n-3} (p-1)!.p^k = \mathcal{O}\left((n-2)!.(n-1)^k\right)$

Hence $T(n)\sim (n-1)!.n^k$ as n tends to $+\infty$